# Redis read-through implementation & tooling example

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, caching, redis, microservices

I am a beginner in Redis. I am interested to introduce Redis into my system to make it a small-scale microservice. I have read the high level concept of Read-Through cache strategy and then imagine the following picture in my mind.

[image]

Let me explain briefly, I will have 2 (or more) domain driven microservices (Payment, Customer) responsible for **UPDATING** (i.e. the "command" part in CQRS) data in their isolated PostgreSql DB schema. For the **QUERY** part, I would like that all of "GET" API requests from my mobile app fetch data from Redis using the Read-Through strategy by having some kind of "PG to Redis Converter" behind the scene (as in the label (6) in the picture).

This is what I think the Read-Through cache is about as far as I understand. But I am trying to search for an example of this kind of converter to integrate with my NodeJS or Java REST API, but I cannot find one. Most example I can find only talk about the concept. And the ones that show the implementation turn out to be more like Cache-Aside strategy.

Please help suggest which tools to use for such converter. Or if it can be configured directly into Redis itself (e.g. using Lua script?). It would be great if it can be done serverlessly using AWS service, but not necessary, thank you.

Comment: It's possible to do read through with RedisGears and a recipe either rgsync, but also https://github.com/RedisGears/rghibernate#read-through

Comment: @PieterCailliau thank you, I will give it a try. It seems RedisGears or writing a custom Redis module is the way to go. It is very surprising that it does not have a popular reliable solution for this.